# anchor button background images aren't displaying as expected on android stock browser.

Tags: android, html, css

I have some buttons which display fine in chrome but on stock android browser the images appear smaller than what they are.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-postSocial">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="twit" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="ggl" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="pin" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-postSocial {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
    float:none;
}
.col-postSocial li {
    display:inline-block;
}
.col-postSocial a {
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
.fb {
background:url('../images/facebook.png') #3b5998;
}
.twit {
background:url('../images/twitter.png') no-repeat top #00aced;
}
.ggl { background:url('../images/google_plus.png') no-repeat top #dd4b39;
}
.pin {
background:url('../images/pinterest.png') no-repeat top #cb2027;
}
```

I'm not sure what to change to make this work on androids stock browser, surely this should work right?

The images are 50 x 100px png but on android the images look more like 25 x 50px, the boxes are still 50x50 so what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it just wanted me to define a size `background-size:50px 100px!important;`